# Android studio on windows 7 error :UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, osmdroid

the error occurred when imported the osmand project :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':OsmAnd:preDexFreeLegacyArmv5Debug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       E:\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --force-jumbo --output E:\Android_test_projects\Osmand-master2\Osmand-master\OsmAnd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\freelegacyarmv5\debug\OsmAnd-java-android-9c283cd307dbfef07359ccbde68a116b21ff0b4f.jar E:\Android_test_projects\Osmand-master2\Osmand-master\OsmAnd-java\build\libs\OsmAnd-java-android.jar
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       ...while parsing com/google/protobuf/AbstractMessage$1.class
>       1 error; aborting

the cause of above error was java 1.8. after changing it to 1.7 i got this run time error

```
      2-11 10:28:55.160  26327-26327/net.osmand V/Zygote﹕ Switching descriptor 34 to /dev/null
02-11 10:28:55.160  26327-26327/net.osmand V/Zygote﹕ Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
02-11 10:28:55.160  26327-26327/net.osmand D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-11 10:28:55.200  26327-26327/net.osmand D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:net.osmand
02-11 10:28:55.200  26327-26327/net.osmand D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
02-11 10:28:55.200  26327-26327/net.osmand D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
02-11 10:28:55.260  26327-26327/net.osmand I/net.osmand﹕ ResourceManager Tiles to load in memory : 162.0
02-11 10:28:55.350  26327-26327/net.osmand D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-11 10:28:55.350  26327-26327/net.osmand W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41653db8)
02-11 10:28:55.350  26327-26327/net.osmand E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.osmand, PID: 26327
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application net.osmand.plus.OsmandApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
            at net.osmand.router.RoutingConfiguration.getDefault(RoutingConfiguration.java:171)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.getBuilder(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:44)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.<init>(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:38)
            at net.osmand.plus.OsmandApplication.onCreate(OsmandApplication.java:165)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4473)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
            at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.setInput(KXmlParser.java:1625)
            at net.osmand.router.RoutingConfiguration.parseFromInputStream(RoutingConfiguration.java:184)
            at net.osmand.router.RoutingConfiguration.getDefault(RoutingConfiguration.java:169)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.getBuilder(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:44)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.<init>(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:38)
            at net.osmand.plus.OsmandApplication.onCreate(OsmandApplication.java:165)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4473)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        02-11 10:29:42.570  26327-26334/net.osmand D/dalvikvm﹕ null clazz in OP_INSTANCE_OF, single-stepping
        02-11 10:33:27.190  26327-26327/net.osmand I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 26327 SIG: 9
        02-11 10:34:10.670  26873-26873/net.osmand D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:net.osmand
        02-11 10:34:10.670  26873-26873/net.osmand D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
        02-11 10:34:10.670  26873-26873/net.osmand D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
        02-11 10:34:10.740  26873-26873/net.osmand I/net.osmand﹕ ResourceManager Tiles to load in memory : 162.0
        02-11 10:34:10.840  26873-26873/net.osmand D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
        02-11 10:34:10.840  26873-26873/net.osmand W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41653db8)
        02-11 10:34:10.840  26873-26873/net.osmand E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: net.osmand, PID: 26873
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application net.osmand.plus.OsmandApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
            at net.osmand.router.RoutingConfiguration.getDefault(RoutingConfiguration.java:171)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.getBuilder(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:44)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.<init>(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:38)
            at net.osmand.plus.OsmandApplication.onCreate(OsmandApplication.java:165)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4473)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
            at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.setInput(KXmlParser.java:1625)
            at net.osmand.router.RoutingConfiguration.parseFromInputStream(RoutingConfiguration.java:184)
            at net.osmand.router.RoutingConfiguration.getDefault(RoutingConfiguration.java:169)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.getBuilder(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:44)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.<init>(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:38)
            at net.osmand.plus.OsmandApplication.onCreate(OsmandApplication.java:165)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4473)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 10:34:58.010  26873-26880/net.osmand D/dalvikvm﹕ null clazz in OP_INSTANCE_OF, single-stepping
```

Comment: `cafebabe` is the correct magic, but the major version 34 refers to a class file compiled with JDK 1.8. Android tools do not support Java 8 yet.

Comment: Yes that helped. thanks. i changed the java to 1.7 the built error is done but now there is run time error .

Comment: The runtime exception is raised because the resource "routing.xml" was not embedded properly (java resource, not an android resource!). How do you include resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I`ve got same issue, i moved all the .java class files to the root package and all errors were gone...

Comment: I had a similar problem and moved the .jar file to the root of the project and the error went away too. I wish I understood why